# What are words where the first letter can be successively removed to form more words called?

Tags: word, english

What is the name of a word such as "Wheat" that when you remove the first letter, it is still a word, down to two letters? 
Ex: Wheat, Heat, Eat, At... Spit, Pit, It. 
What is the longest such word, in the English language?

Answer (score 5):

The process of removing the first letter (e.g. greengages->reengages) is called beheadment. What you're looking for is the longest progressive beheadment to a two-letter word. Chris Cole, in *Wordplay* (pub. Sterling) cites this example:

> prestates restates estates states tates ates tes es

Comment: tes? es?
https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/explore/two-letter-words

Longer than "wheat" i found only "splash", but that dictionary has problem with "sh"

Comment: not to mention tates and ates.